# How to split string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I'm trying to split the value from the `model_interested` column so that from the whole data only model display

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(model_interested, 20, CHARINDEX('model', model_interested)) AS model_interested 
FROM cust
```

[image]

From the image in `model_interested` column I wish to only display

```
"model":"A180"
"model":"A200 AMG FL"
```

I have tried splitting by number of characters but I don't think it's the right way.

Comment: If you're storing JSON in the database and you're using SQL Server 2016 or newer ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask]. Please read the first two paragraphs of the [sql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) and [`CHARINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(model_interested, CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested) + LEN('"model":"'), CHARINDEX('"', model_interested, CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested) + LEN('"model":"')) - (CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested) + LEN('"model":"')))
FROM table_name
```

To get the whole property (with property name and value) you can use the following solution:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(model_interested, CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested), CHARINDEX('"', model_interested, CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested) + LEN('"model":"')) - CHARINDEX('"model":"', model_interested) + 1)
FROM table_name
```

You can also use [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql) to get the expected value, but you have to change the data to a valid JSON value:

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(REPLACE(model_interested, '{[', '[{'), ']}', '}]'), '$[0].model')
FROM table_name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=643e67075425bbd5bac910636a049f2d)

Answer (score 0):

If using earlier version of SQL server than 2016, then you can write a query as:

```
;with cte as
(
 SELECT   
       Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS model_interested  
 FROM  (
         SELECT CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE([model_interested], '.', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML)
                as  model_interested_xml
         FROM  @cust

        ) AS A CROSS APPLY model_interested_xml.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)  
    )
select model_interested
from cte
where CHARINDEX('model',model_interested) > 0
```

demo here: https://rextester.com/CCW41495